# Using React components inside KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, knockout.js

We have a big web application mostly built using KnockoutJS. I'm looking at if there is a possibility to migrate to React, but in a way that require rewriting the entire application. My idea was to use a bottom-up approach: start by replacing the basic building blocks one by one.

I was inspired by some [prior work](http://intelligiblebabble.com/making-reactjs-and-knockoutjs-play-nice/) to call ReactDOM.render inside a KnockoutJS binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.react = {
    init() {
        return {controlsDescendantBindings: true};
    },
    update(element, valueAccessor) {
        const {component, props} = valueAccessor();
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(component, props), element);
    }
};
```

Knockout has its own dependency tracking system, so it will call the update method whenever some data changes.

It works perfectly, and the component is re-rendered to reflect any changes to data. However, it breaks down when data is updated inside a React event handler. E.g., this component does not work as expected:

```
const Input = function ({value}) {
    return <input type="text" 
                  value={value()} 
                  onChange={e => value(e.target.value)}/>;
}
```

Note: value in this case is a ko.observable, and calling it like in the event handler will cause the bindingHandler's update method to be called, which in turn calls ReactDOM.render. However, this render only works once, after that the component stops updating.

[The issue is demonstrated in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/ShinzouNingen/pen/wvazPWp?editors=1011). Click the box and try to type something. One update goes through, after than, the component's function stops being called.

Edit: I believe the issue is that the second call to ReactDOM.render (when the value is updated by the user in the onChange handler) is not synchronous. This means that Knockout's dependency detection cannot work and any subsequent calls no longer call the update method of the binding handler.

Can this be circumvented somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I guessed, the issue seems to be that ReactDOM.render is asynchronous in some cases - in this case when called from an event handler in React.

This means that if you dereference any observables that you depend on in the update method itself, Knockout's dependency tracking mechanism works as expected. This is why the modification Gawel1908 proposed makes it work - not because the value is "reset", but because props.value is dereferenced.

I decided to instead use a convention: always unwrap any such observables in the valueAccessor itself:

```
<div data-bind="react: { component: Input, props: { value: val(), setValue: val }}">
</div>
```

And don't unwrap it in the component:

```
const Input = function ({value, setValue}) {
  return <input 
           type="text" 
           value={value} 
           onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}/>;
}
```

[Updated, working codepen.](https://codepen.io/ShinzouNingen/pen/VwLmYBd)

Comment: how do you handle cleanup for react component ? i am also using the same approach and when i move to another page i am still seeing components that were rendered in previous page

Answer (score 1):

For me worked:

```
 update(element, valueAccessor) {
    const {component, props} = valueAccessor();
    props.value(props.value());
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(component, props), element);
}
```

if you refresh your `observable` it will work but unfortunetaly i don't know how.

Comment: I think this proves what I already believed might be the error - that ReactDOM.render is not synchronous when called from an event handler. I might be able to craft a workaround from this information.